# Setting store object from axios in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I am working on an app, written in React.js, where I get data from a JSON feed and then I'll use this data in various ways in the app.

I make the call to the feed via axios:

```js
module.exports = {
  getMainPlaylist: function () {
    var requestUrl = `${MAIN_PLAYLIST_FEED_URL}`;

    return axios.get(requestUrl).then(function (res) {
      return res.data.playlist
    }, function (err) {
      alert('error');
    });
  }
};
```

In my app.jsx file, I have the following:

```js
store.subscribe(() => {
  var state = store.getState();
  console.log('New state: ', state);
});

var mainPlaylist = MainPlaylistAPI.getMainPlaylist();
store.dispatch(actions.addMainPlaylist(mainPlaylist));
```

In my actions file, I have this:

```js
export var addMainPlaylist = (mainPlaylist) => {
  return {
    type: 'ADD_MAIN_PLAYLIST',
    mainPlaylist
  }
};
```

In my reducers file I have this:

```js
export var playlistReducer = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_MAIN_PLAYLIST':
      return [
        ...state,
        ...action.mainPlaylist
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

When I was using the state as normal to get the data it was working fine but I think because I'm trying to use the store with a web service it's probably not working because of the asynchronous process.

When I log to the console I get this:

[console 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zd4Wu.png)

[console 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DUy0u.png)

I come from a .NET background so I'm fairly new to working only in JavaScript and I have no idea where to start to fix this.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this myself.

Axios is a promise-based client so I used .then() where I call it.

So this:

```js
var mainPlaylist = MainPlaylistAPI.getMainPlaylist();
store.dispatch(actions.addMainPlaylist(mainPlaylist));
```

Become this:

```js
MainPlaylistAPI.getMainPlaylist().then(function (data) {
  store.dispatch(actions.addMainPlaylist(data));
}, function(e) {
  // Handle errors
});
```

Comment: I would suggest you use some package to handle network requests. Can be redux or relay/graphql